# React arrays push method

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a chat application in React, I have a checkbox beside text when I click checkbox I take the text message.
I just want to store the text in array. When I store the text I use this code:

```
this.setState(() =>{
     this.state.allMessage.push(message.content.text);
});
```

But I can store only one, let's say I click checkbox and I send to the array "Hello world". Then I click checkbox "Hello Guys", and only this is stored to array. I just want to add like this:

`allMessage:  ["Hello World" , "Hello Guys"]` 
How can add like this.
Now, when I push "Hello Guys" then "Hello world" is deleting automatically.

Comment: Sorry, can't understand exactly what you need, but, you want to remove the last message from array every time a new message is pushed? If so, isn't just clear the array then push? or even, why an array?

Comment: I just want to add array to string but when i use this push method not work. For example: I have a 3 string  "Example1" "example2"  "example3"  ı did this.state.allMessage.push"Example1"] its okay ı send it. but when i try again this.state.AllMessage.push("Example2") its also okay but  "Example1" is deleting how can i store ? ı dont want to deleting first one

Answer (score 2):

Don't mutate state:

```
this.setState({
   allMessages: [
     ...this.state.allMessages, 
     message.content.text
   ]
})
```

This might not solve your exact problem, but it's the first step.

> like that how can add like this. When i push "Hello Guys" "Hello world" deleting automatically.

Do you event want an array then if you only want to keep one item in state at a time?

You could do this:

```
onToggleMessageCheckbox(e) {
  this.setState({
   allMessages: e.target.checked ? [e.target.value] : []
  });
}
```

If you do want to maintain the state of both checkboxes:

```
onToggleMessageCheckbox(e) {
  this.setState(state => ({
   ...state, 
   allMessages: e.target.checked ? state.allMessages.concat(e.target.value) : state.allMessages.filter(m => m !== e.target.value)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
this.setState(() =>{
 allMessages:[...this.state.allMessages,message.content.text]
});
```

It means that you are modifying the state value by keeping all existing value and add your new value.